# How to limit the input to the Scanner?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputInt = checkInput(in, "Enter an integer and a base: ");
    int inputBase = checkInput(in, "");
}

public static int checkInput(Scanner in, String prompt) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
        in.next();
        System.out.println("Sorry, that is an invalid input.");
        System.out.print(prompt);
    }
    return in.nextInt();
}
```

This method works and doesn't return any bad input i.e., ; p "hello".

My question is how can I limit the number of inputs the scanner will read. Say I input `5 five % ;` but I only want `5` and `five` to be passed in to my method and the rest dropped.

I looked through the Java API but couldn't find a method that would limit the amount of user input accepted. Am I just missing it or is there another way to do this?

Edit: I have tried using the .length() method to limit the input but then that doesn't allow integers greater than the .length() parameter.

Comment: What do you want to limit off of?  String length, words, etc.?

Comment: I want the user to input 2 integers, say 5 2. The Scanner input reads spaces as a delimiter. But if the user inputs more than 2 inputs, say 5 2 8 9, I only want the Scanner method to take in the first 2 values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working sample of how you could accomplish what you need.  I broke it up so that the user is prompted once for each input which makes it easier to validate.  I changed your `checkInput` method to `getInput` which only returns valid user input as a `String` where it is then converted into an `int`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(getInput(in, "Enter an integer: "));
    int inputBase = Integer.parseInt(getInput(in, "Enter a base: "));
    System.out.println("Int: " + inputInt + ", base: " + inputBase);
}

public static String getInput(Scanner in, String prompt) { // Get valid user input
    System.out.print(prompt); // Tell user what to input
    String text = "";
    while (true) { // Keep looping until valid input is found
        text = in.nextLine(); // Get input from stdin
        if(isInteger(text)) // Check if they put in integer
            break; // Exit loop
        System.out.print("Try again, " + prompt); // Wasn't valid, prompt again
    } 
    return text; // Return valid user input
}

private static boolean isInteger(String str) { // Check if string is integer
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str); // If this doesn't fail then it's integer
        return true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false; // Wasn't integer
    }
}
```

Sample run:

```
Enter an integer: 2 dog five 3
Try again, Enter an integer: 2
Enter a base: cat
Try again, Enter a base: 3
Int: 2, base: 3
```

It helps to separate functionality - you were trying to read input, validate input, and convert to `int` all in one method.  If you break it up it becomes easier to manage.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
String string = sc.findInLine(".{500}"); // length of your input you want
```

**findInLine(String pattern)**

method of Scanner class of `java.util package`. This method returns a String object that satisfies the pattern specified as method argument.

[see this article](http://javatutorialhq.com/java/util/scanner-class-tutorial/findinline-string-pattern-method-example/)

Comment: nice feature but if user enter more than 5 for example, it does not show any error to him or her?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only get the first two words (or strings delimited by spaces) you can use the `str.split(" ");` method.
For example:

```
String input = in.nextLine(); // Gets the next line the user enters (as a String)
String[] inputWords = input.split(" "); // inputWords[0] is first word, inputWords[1] 
                                        // is second word... etc
String validInput = inputWords[0] + " " + inputWords[1]; // Combines the first and 
// second words into a string, so if you had "5 five %" validInput would be "5 five"
// inputWords[0] is "5", inputWords[1] is "five", inputWords[3] is "%" etc for any other words...
```

This will essentially limit the number of inputs to two words.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think u should edit your answer cuz it seems the op wants the input to be length 5

Comment: This seems like it could work. I will give it a shot.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. FYI, if you input only 1 value it breaks but I guess I can catch that error.

Comment: @user2453911 Be warry though - this doesn't check anywhere to see if the input was an integer which seemed to be part of your "checking for valid input" requirement.

Comment: That is true. But it was the first(joe's worked as well) to limit it to 2 inputs. Though it seems it is not possible to limit the Scanner input when reading in the value as int.

Comment: @user2453911 I recommended in my answer to break it up into two separate input reads - makes the error checking/validation simpler.

Comment: @Andrew_CS but even when you input more values in one line it overloads it. Look at my comment of the output. I did give it +1(not sure if that does anything) because of the thoroughness of the answer.

Comment: @user2453911 I saw your comment and replied - read my comment - it was a copy and paste error.

Answer (score 1):

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    System.out.println ("enter a 2 numbers");

    String s;

    s = scan.nextLine();

    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(s);

    int one = scan2.nextInt();
    int two = scan2.nextInt();

    System.out.println (" int 1 = " + one + " int 2 = " + two);
```

enter a 2 numbers
23 45 68 96 45
 int 1 = 23 int 2 = 45

Process completed.

Comment: Thank you. FYI, this also breaks with only 1 input.

Comment: You should remove your other answer.

Comment: cant give away the entire solution now can i :P , but in honesty i didn't test that, only checked the problem at hand and alright will do(i'm new on SO)